# How to get live table row count in DynamoDb programmatically in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I wrote something like below code in my ASP.NET WEB API. I want to get the live row count t0 display in my application. The problem with the below code is it's showing **Scanned count** as 7134. But actual value is in millions.

```
            var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
            AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
            var request = new ScanRequest
            {
                TableName = "exampleTable",
                Select = Select.COUNT
            };
            var response = client.ScanAsync(request, cancellationToken).Result;
            var totalCount = response.Count.ToString();
            return totalCount;
```

Comment: Your code most certainly does no pagination, so you get only the first 1MB of data.  Check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination

Comment: @Raj - as Dunedan said + do you know that quering with Scan through millions of requests can cost some serious money? What is your use-case?

Comment: I am working on IOT project. so, my requirement is to show live row count of the table. example you can see this link https://rotimatic.com/ it's showing the count.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'live' row count?

Also, if you have only a few pieces of code that insert into your Dynamo table you could insert a record specifically for maintaining count, and then update this record's counter whenever inserting / deleting from the table.. It's more work, but may be better than incurring the costs involved in scanning millions of records, multiple times a day.